# Solr - Remove collapsed groups from final result

Tags: solr, fieldcollapsing

I'm using Apache Solr 7.1 and using [FieldCollapse](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_1/collapse-and-expand-results.html) feature to group documents based on a field.

Sample Document:
`{id: "ASDF1234",count: 10, event: "Create"}`

Sample request: http://localhost:8983/solr/brandNewComp000/select?fq={!collapse%20field=id%20sort=count%20desc}&q=*:*&rows=30

Grouping is working fine. But in the final response I want to exclude few documents based on a condition on event field. That is I want to exclude few collapsed documents in the final response.

Is it possible to do that?

Note: If I add another filter query (`fq`) or query (`q`) to filter on 'event' field then that filtering 'happens before grouping' which is NOT the behavior I am looking for. I want to exclude documents after collapsing is done. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you don't want to filter out before the grouping. That is a reasonable approach. Otherwise, you may have to filter by yourself in your application.

Comment: If I filter before collapsing, such documents will not be participating in collapsing. I want all documents selected by query to participate in collapsing and eliminate few of the groups based on some condition. 
Think of `group by` and `having` clause in SQL; I am looking for similar to `having` clause in solr

Comment: I don't think solr has something equivalent to `having` clause in SQL. However, you can make your own plugin to do some behavior you want. see https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPlugins